# sp_executesql parameter size limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have captured a query generated by Entity Framework where one of the parameters can store a large amount (400,000+ characters) of text information in an `nvarchar(max)` field. The problem I have is that when executing the statement the string is truncated to 43679 characters. This happens if Entity Framework executes the query or if I execute from a query window.

Is there a limit on the size of an entire sp_executesql statement or the size of any individual parameter with the statement?

**Table Schema**

[image]

**Generated Query**

I have excluded the large string (Markup) for spaces sake.

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [CDP].[Content]([ProjectId], [Version], [DateAdded], [Owner], [Markup], [State])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT [ContentId]
FROM [CDP].[Content]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ContentId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 datetime2(7),@3 nvarchar(128),@4 nvarchar(max) ,@5 int',@0=193,@1=0,@2='2015-07-17 12:48:22.1168801',@3=N'<System>',@4=N'[[400000 charater string]]',@5=1
```

Comment: Have you verified with `select len(markup)` post insert to eliminate display truncation at 43679?

Comment: @AlexK.I have taken the resultant table, selected a number of rows and pasted the data into Notepad++ and the length of the Markup field consistently tops out at 43679.

Comment: I mean SSMS limits display of long text to a maximum number of chars (cant remember what it is) I would double check with a `select`

Comment: i think the display for that field gets truncated. can you try exporting the data from that table to a file using `bcp`?

Comment: @AlexK. Damn, you are right. Management studio is only showing part of the data. If I use this query, select projectid, len(Markup) from cdp.content order by len(Markup) desc, the lengths are shown correctly. Wasted three hours on that one. Create and answer and I will mark it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Management Studio and most other editors will truncate the display of long text at a certain point, you should verify the length of the inserted data by querying the table it `select len(markup) ...`

Comment: Thanks Alex. Appreciate your help